# Native map not shown in LayeredLayout on Android device with Codename One

Tags: java, android, google-maps, codenameone

For 2-3 weeks I've been using my app in development on a real Android device. So far it has always shown Google Maps on the device and OSM on the simulator.

Today I made some changes -namely added a button on top of the Map, and sent the build. CN1 and CN1libs were updated before the build was sent. Now when I test it on the device, no map is displayed and I get **404: Not found**. If you ever ask about the behaviour in the simulator it still works as expected (but it uses OSM with MapComponent).

Here is my code to lay the map down (the map initialization has not changed):

```
Container mapWithButton = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(BorderLayout.centerCenter(googleMap),
FlowLayout.encloseRight(locateMeButton));
this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mapWithButton);
```

I have had a look at [MapContainer history](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/commits/master/GoogleMaps) but the recent changes only deal with `longPressListener`. Please note that the native Maps app is working well on the device. Debugging through DDMS did not help (the same error appears on the screen).

Did I forget to update or add a build hint?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might be related to permission or change of certificate that you use, native Google Maps are bound to a specific certificate and permissions and something might have changed in the Google cloud settings or in the app that causes this failure. The way to debug this is to plug the device with a cable and look at the ddms/logcat output where it should be listed

Comment: Without changing anything, if I do `this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, googleMap); `  (instead of using LayeredLayout) then the map is displayed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the 404 error had nothing to do with the map but with the added `MapListener` which was trying to fetch data from an address that is not yet available when moving the map.

Yet the fact to make the map actually appears, it is required to enclose it via `BorderLayout.center()` and not the `BorderLayout.centerCenter()` alternative.

So I have no explanations to provide but the following code displays the map and the button as expected (note the `BorderLayout.center` instead of `BorderLayout.centerCenter`.

```
Container mapWithButton = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
                                        BorderLayout.center(googleMap),
                                        FlowLayout.encloseRight(locateMeButton));

this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mapWithButton);
```

Comment: `BorderLayout.centerCenter()` gives the component its preferred size which can be zero as the native code works on its own thread. `BorderLayout.center()` will work.